# Using TSQL, in a subquery select statement I want to return a row for a column as NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

```
        WHEN qt.Id = 10 THEN
             (
             SELECT 
                 OptionId = NULL
                 ,AnswerString = NULL
                 ,san.AnswerNumber as AnswerBinary
                 ,Total = COUNT(*) 
             FROM dbo.SurveyAnswers AS san
             WHERE san.QuestionId = sq.Id
             GROUP BY san.AnswerNumber
             FOR JSON AUTO
             )
```

So in the above subquery, how could I force SQL to return a column named OptionId that would be NULL

Comment: case when only return a scalar value it would help if you have a [mre] with tables data and a resultset

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and your complete query (minimal of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is that `OptionId` does not appear in the row because of `NULL` value. then add this option:

```
FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

`INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` cause that the keys with null value, to include in JSON.